# Android studio OnTouchListener

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am trying to create a app for music. It is being developed in Android Studio. I want this button to start the sound when I press down and stop when I release the button, but I can't make it work.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;  

import android.os.Bundle;   

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;    

import android.view.MotionEvent;   

import android.view.View;  

import android.widget.Button;   

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MediaPlayer minus5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.min5);

        final Button play_min5 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.min5);

        play_min5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // PRESSED
                    minus5.start();
                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // RELEASED
                    minus5.stop();
                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: The button will simply not press. i am able to play the sound If i use the Clicklistener. So my guess is that there was something wrong with the code i wrote.

Comment: What do you mean with 'the button will simply not press'? Does the button not give a visual indicator that it's being pressed? Is your event not being triggered? Both?

Comment: Both of the ones you mentioned, the button will not trigger the event and it will also not indicate that it is pressed. 
sorry for the bad explanation on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
Simply write return true instead of false and it works like a charm.

```
play_min5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        // Your code here
        return true;
    }
});
```